# Search query not showing up in URL in simple search app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, search

I'm trying to build an app that searches twitter for images. Before I get there, I need to jump over the intimidating hurdle of constructing a working search field that feeds a value into a function.

In my `index.html.erb` file that's controlled by the `Pages controller`, I have this code:

```
<%= form_tag root_path ({:controller => "pages", :action => "search", :method => "get", :class => "grabTweets" }) do %>
<%= text_field_tag :tweets, params[:tweets] %>
<% end %>
```

In my `Pages controller` I have:

```
  def search

    def grabTweets
      @tweet = Twitter.search(params[:tweets] + "[pic] "+" path.com/p/", :rpp => 3, :result_type => "recent").map do |status|
      @tweet = "#{status.text}" #class = string
      @urls = URI::extract(@tweet, "http") #returns an array of strings
    end 
  end       


end
```

Two problems:

My search query isn't being passed into the grabTweets function as proven by the URL after the search is performed:

`http://localhost:3000/?action=search&class=grabTweets&method=get` (the search query was the word "bridge"

What's wrong with my code that the search query isn't performing correctly.

Should my code that's in the controller be placed in `def home` or `def search`, given that I want the search results to show up in the `root_path` and don't intend to change pages?

Thanks in advance for the help! I'm thoroughly stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to read a book introducting Rails, as there seem to be many fundamentals you are missing.

You have an action for the page you are on (which you seem to call 'home') and an action for the search results. Your form needs to call the url for the search action. That would look like this:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "pages", :action => "search"}, {:method => "get", :class => "grabTweets"}) do %>
...
```

(See the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) for more details on the form_tag method)

In that state, it will call the search action (which should not have another method called `grabTweets` nested inside it - that makes no sense) which will then render search.html.erb (presumably a page of search results).

In your routes file, you need a route for both home and search.

If you want the page to update without refreshing the page, then you need to use `:remote => true` on the form and handle the response using AJAX.

If you want the two pages to be the same, but with one containing results, then either move the search functionality into the home action and only call it if params[:tweets] is populated, or just have both actions render the same template.

I would recommend reading through the [Rendering Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) and the [Controllers Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) to learn more.